# SQL query on PHPMyAdmin to insert data not working

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Following is my SQL query:

*Attempt 1*

```
INSERT INTO `product`(`productid`, `title`, `category`, `description`) 
VALUES (NULL,`iMac`,`Desktop`,`With its enhanced, big and beautiful display, the new Apple iMac M-D093-B/A 21.5 Desktop Computer renders your movies, photos, web pages and other graphics in truly jaw-dropping detail.`)
```

*Attempt 2*

```
INSERT INTO `product`(`productid`, `title`, `category`, `description`) 
VALUES(` `,`iMac`,`Desktop`,`With its enhanced, big and beautiful display, the new Apple iMac M-D093-B/A 21.5 Desktop Computer renders your movies, photos, web pages and other graphics in truly jaw-dropping detail.`)
```

I keep getting an error of : `MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 0.0003 sec )`

I don't understand what am i doing wrong. Here is my column name list

```
1  productid int(11)    
2  title varchar(100)
3  category varchar(100)
4  description varchar(2000)
```

table name:product

Comment: Your quoting is partly incorrect. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/mysql-when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks  The string literals need to be in single quotes, not backticks.

Comment: i have tried that too. It doesn't seem to work.

Comment: does Insert operation returns empty result set (i.e. zero rows)? I m confused...

Comment: it did returned error : MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 0.0003 sec ) when i tried inserting but now i've got the solution:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the values, use the `'` character, not this one: ``` (sorry, I'll have to find out how to put a single backtick into an inline code block in Markdown...)

```
INSERT INTO `product`(`productid`, `title`, `category`, `description`) 
VALUES (NULL,'iMac','Desktop','With its enhanced, big and beautiful display, the new Apple iMac M-D093-B/A 21.5 Desktop Computer renders your movies, photos, web pages and other graphics in truly jaw-dropping detail.')
```

And this should work... [Here is the SQLfiddle for it](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/93df3/1).

**EDIT**
This is the solution as per zour table definition:

```
INSERT INTO `product`(`title`, `category`, `description`) 
VALUES ('iMac','Desktop','With its enhanced, big and beautiful display, the new Apple iMac M-D093-B/A 21.5 Desktop Computer renders your movies, photos, web pages and other graphics in truly jaw-dropping detail.')
```

You had two things you forgot to mention:
 * `productid` is a `PRIMARY KEY` (and hence, automatically `NOT NULL`) column -- any inserts with a `NULL` in that column will fail
 * `productid` is an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column -- you don't even have to include it in the `INSERT` statement, it will get filled with an unique value each time you insert a row

[The SQL fiddle for this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/08fc1/1)

Comment: I believe the pattern for an inline backtick is backtick,backslash,backtick,backtick... `\``

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Thanks a lot, I was just about to try the good old escaping. EDIT: it works in a comment, but doesn't work in an answer?(I get 3 backticks...)

Comment: Hmm, it worked in my comment but not when I tried to edit your answer.. That might be a bug. I'm going to check meta.

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work. Is inserting data through Sql query affected by the version you are using?i am new to this so i really don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: @kiranpatel please post your table definition (CREATE TABLE statement) to be sure. Is it not that the `productid` column is a `PRIMARY KEY`? Or at least not null?

Comment: CREATE TABLE `product` (
`productid` int( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`title` varchar( 100 ) NOT NULL ,
`category` varchar( 100 ) NOT NULL ,
`description` longtext NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY ( `productid` ) ) ENGINE = MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1;

Comment: @ ppeterka your solution was correct. i had error when i pasted your answer but then i retyped the solution(query) and it worked! i'm really greatful to you for helping me to solve the problem. thank you very much.:)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `'` with every `varchar`, datatype, so in your case:

```
INSERT INTO product(productid, title, category, description) VALUES 
(
    NULL,
    'iMac',
    'Desktop', 
    'With its enhanced, big and beautiful display, the new Apple iMac M-D093-B/A 21.5 Desktop Computer renders your movies, photos, web pages and other graphics in truly jaw-dropping detail.'
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response But this query also get the same error.:( (MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 0.0004 sec )

Comment: is productid your primary key? if yes, this must not be NULL

Comment: yes it is. i thought since i have added as Auto Increment, it would upload a digit byitself, woudn't it?

Comment: does it work when you change NULL to any number?

Comment: Post your create table statement, and all your queries so that we can find the error

Comment: CREATE TABLE `product` (
`productid` int( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`title` varchar( 100 ) NOT NULL ,
`category` varchar( 100 ) NOT NULL ,
`description` longtext NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY ( `productid` ) ) ENGINE = MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1;

thts the table it's not working. please i really need help.

Comment: I tried my solution in phpmyadmin and it works just fine with your create table statement and my query. I think the problem is somewhere else. Have you tried other queries on other tables? try SELECT UPPER('foo') FROM DUAL; to find out if your database works.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion i got the answer. the problem was the use of backtick and single quotes plus the primary key in table. i really appreciate your help.:)